# CSS - Issue with z-index of blinking curosr of input box in IE-11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In IE-11 when the typed text string is longer in the input box, the blinking cursor of input box moves over the div having id "Second".

Please suggest how I can stop this.

Refer "http://jsfiddle.net/rhcpz4uq/"

OR

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>Z-Index Problem</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="first" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;  display:inline; position:absolute;">
    <input id="input1" type="text" value=""></input>
  </div>
  <div id="second" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; left: 50px; background-color: pink; display:inline; position:absolute;">
  </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: could you please explain why you are placing the div over the top of it?

Comment: why not shorten the text box till the left edge of the pink div if its hidden anyway?

Comment: @Banana: this question does seem slightly odd, doesn't it? Not sure why OP is using absolute positioning on their elements, nor why the first element is so large? Also, what is this 'pink' representing?

Comment: @jbutler483 it seems like an XY question, it would be better if op explains **what** he is trying to achieve and we will help him with the **how**

Comment: @Rhumborl i can confirm this behavior in IE 11, when text reaches the pink box, everything disappears behind the box except the blinking cursos which stays on top. weird indeed, might be engine issue.

Comment: In real scenario the pink div represents a draggable div so when a user drags the div over that text box the cursor appears on it .

Comment: But surely when the user is 'dragging', the text box won't have focus (hence no blinking cursor)?

Comment: you could write your own textbox using a custom div, and simply hide the caret when its behind the draggable div...

Comment: @jbutler483 I have used e.stoppropogation and e.preventdefault for the draggable div so the textbox is not losing focus while dragging.

Comment: @Banana thanks for your reply but I need to use the default input boxes only. Is there any other way to hide the cursor.

Comment: it seems there is no way to alter the caret, your best bet is to reimplement the whole thing or use a plugin for customized textboxes. may i ask why would you want to hide the text box with the div in the first place? you can disallow the user from moving the div over the text box, ie: if the div is placed of the textbox, slide it a bit down or something. or give it a red shade if use moves it over the textbox...

Answer (score -2):

Try setting the z-index to something like

```
<div id="second" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; left: 50px;
 background-color: pink; z-index:100; display:inline; position:absolute;">
</div>
```